# How to find pre known bigrams or any ngrams from a document

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I have a list of known bi-grams and tri-grams which are known to me , I want to find all these n-grams that exist in my document , I have tried gensim library phrases library but it will give the bigrams based on some score crossing a threshold but I want detect those n-grams which I already have. How can I do it.eg words like 'dark' and 'chocolate' should be combined into one word "dark-chocolate" and so on.

I want to find the words that form aroma and taste of a product like "shoe_polish" or "baked_toast" so on such words which combine two words and then i will calculate embeddings of these phrased words pairs using word2vec. I already have list of such aromas words unigrams, bigrams and trigram and i will extract more from sentence but i want atleast does phrases which  already i know to be detected atlest

Comment: Gensim's `Phrases` would be overkill for your need, as it attempts to statistically-deduce which word-pairs could be usefully combined. What's the form of your "known bi-grams & tri-grams"? What's the form of your document?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have editted , i hope now it's more clear.